# DDoS attack handling strategies

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos, amazon-waf

I am building a website to carry out a survey and this would store some answers and user data. Obviously, I want to keep costs low and within what the free tier offers. I am trying to build a low-cost solution for mitigating DDoS attacks. Here is what I have come up with but not sure if I am going in the right direction. I plan to put my frontend as well backend service behind CloudFront. I would put AWS WAF and Shield on this CloudFront. Along with that, I plan to add two WAF rules:

- Every request should have a "user-agent" header
- Requests should originate only from a specific country i.e the one
  with my target audience

Along with this, I plan to add a Recaptcha to ensure only human users interact with my application just as a deterrent from cost perspective. Any other suggestion or feedback is really appreciated. Please note: cost is a huge factor.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Shield, CloudFront and WAF should be sufficient for your use case. Use the geo restrictions but I don’t think a header check will add any value as it’s so easy to spoof. Additionally you may think about using auto scaling for your backend to achieve more resilience but be careful with the scaling cost, have a proper scaling policy and set alarms (especially a billing alarm if you don’t have one already) and notifications for scaling events.

Check this whitepaper for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**FluxCDN, DDoS-Guard, Cloudflare, Stackpath would be an good option.**

- Use GEO restrictions (China, India ...) and Challenge the requests (Captcha).
- Block empty user-agent and user agents from bots for example "python-requests" if you don't need them.
- Block an IP from accessing your site if it reaches the Threshold (Rate limit).
- Block bad ASN from accessing your site.
- Use an JS challenge to challenge the legitmacy of the request.
- Cache static files (pngs, htmls, ...)
- Block HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.2 if not needed (Blocks 99% of all DDoS attacks)