# Is there functionality in google cloud armor that can mitigate slowloris attacks?

Tags: google-app-engine, ddos, google-cloud-armor

I got message from security team that our app hosted on App Engine is vulnerable to slowloris DDOS attacks.
After searching around Internet I found out that such kind of attack can be mitigated by Web Servers or L7 Load Balancers if configured correctly. But I didn't find any information that explicitly points out that Google Cloud Armor supports such functionality.

The only web page, where Cloud Armor and slowloris DDOS are mentioned in one article, I found is this one: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/identifying-and-protecting-against-the-largest-ddos-attacks

Does somebody have experince with protecting App Engine against slow DDOS attacks and can share links or materials?

Comment: App Engines sits behind the GFE (Google Front End). I do not believe that App Engine is vulnerable to Slowloris. Please provide more details on what vulnerability was found and how to reproduce it.

Comment: SecOps guy says that they are forbidden to perform full DDOS against gcloud infrastructure by gcloud policies but with the help of Nessus they get  10000 ms time difference between connections and then suspended this particular scan.
It could be reproduced by free version of nessus too.

Comment: A 10,000 ms connection is not Slowloris.

Answer (score 1):

You cloud use Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ in order to mitigate L7 attacks.
Slowloris isn't new anymore its easy to mitigate and cloudflare has such Protection.
You could also rate limit requests per second per IP on your google cloud armor webserver.

Comment: Thanks but according company rules we are allowed to use gcloud native solutions only.
From my understanding limiting requests per second per IP won't help to mitigate slowloris attack. Limiting number of connections a single IP address is allowed to attempt should help.

Comment: You could also block HTTP version 1.0 1.1 1.2 if you don't need them.

See my full DDoS mitigation strategy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67825764/ddos-attack-handling-strategies/68226200#68226200